# Moving Database from Sybase to SQL Server: ODBC not recognised named parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, odbc, sybase

I'm updating an old project, moving its data source from Sybase to SQL Server. The data structures are identical (they're both copies of a commercial database - the Sybase version has been discontinued).

Because it's pretty old, it uses ODBC to connect. The connection strings originally specified a DSN. I've managed to connect to the SQL Server using both a raw connection string and a replacement DSN.

It executes code against the database by pulling command text from a config file and adding named parameters, like so:

```
var args = new Dictionary<string, object>() 
{ 
    { "@myFirstParam", "myFirstValue" }, 
    { "@mySecondParam", "mySecondValue" }
}

IDbCommand cmd = Connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandTimeout = Command.Timeout;

cmd.CreateParameters(Command.Parameters, args);
cmd.CommandText = [fetched from config]

IDataReader reader = null;
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

This all used to work fine with Sybase.

However, when I run it against SQL, when the reader executes I get the following error:

> ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@myFirstVariable".

I get this error whether I specify the connection as a DSN or a raw string. Stepping through the code, the parameter is certainly declared and has a valid value.

Reading up around this, it appears that this behaviour is to be expected. [The Microsoft Documentation on ODBC connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/binding-parameters-odbc?view=sql-server-ver15) says you can only use named parameters if you're calling a stored procedure, which I am not. Apparently the correct method is to put "?" characters in the command text and ODBC will insert the parameters by index.

If this is correct, I have no idea how this code ever worked with Sybase. I have another project which uses the same code for data loading, specifying named parameters and passing them into SQL command specified in config, but it's pointing at a different SQL Server database.

I presume this may be something to do with the configuration of the database, but I'm pretty lost on what to try from here. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `i might be mistaken, but Sybase(ASE) odbc also uses positional placement of parameters. for eg. select @mySecondParam, @myFirstParam might not give you the result you would've expected.`

Comment: @lptr That's what I've read: yet it worked before I swapped out sybase for SQL

Comment: did you use OLEDB to connect to sybase(ase)? (i have definitely encountered such an issue some time ago) values of @vars are not substituted by name, but positional, as they appear in the query.

Comment: No it's ODBC connecting via DSN

Comment: You mentioned you have the same code pointing to a different Microsoft SQL Server database and it works using the ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server ODBC driver. I don't see how that could work as '?' parameter markers are required, AFAIK. Can you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the working code to your question?

Comment: Adding that if you only use the `IDb` ADO.NET interfaces, it might not be a heavy lift to use a managed `SqlClient` driver. That will perform better than ODBC in managed code for large result sets too.

Comment: both OLE&ODBC providers for Sybase(ASE) work with named parameters but the values are "substituted" by position/index. select @a, @b & add("@b", 2), add("@a", 1) will return/select 2, 1 and (not 1, 2 as one would expect). (tested with 15.7 version). ADO.NET works fine as already suggested. You could also adjust the commandtext in code, by replacing each ParameterName with ? and use ODBC.